# Convert float* to jfloatArray using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I obtain a float* in my c++ function and i need convert it in jfloatArray to return to my Java code.

How can i convert float* to jfloatArray?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ and JNI - How to pass an array into a jfloatArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541568/c-and-jni-how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-jfloatarray)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert float* to jfloatArray, you can use NewFloatArray,

You can use code below:

- Variable "data" is just simple example, so you can use your code.
- Also, modify com_your_packagename to your real packagename.
- You must change dot of your package name to underbar. (com.your.packagename --> com_your_packagename)

---

```
jfloatArray Java_com_your_packagename_farrayFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    jfloatArray result;
    result = (*env)->NewFloatArray(env, 3);

    float* data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
    data[0] = 123;  data[1] = 456;  data[2] = 789;

    (*env)->SetFloatArrayRegion(env, result, 0, 3, data);
    free(data);

    return result;
}
```

OR

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_com_your_packagename_farrayFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {

jfloatArray result;
    result = env->NewFloatArray(3);

    float* data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
    data[0] = 123;  data[1] = 456;  data[2] = 789;

    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, 3, data);
    free(data);
    return result;
};
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers and `malloc` for `data`?  Why not just `float data[3];`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This means dynamic allocation. If you cannot get size of array at compile time, you can just define pointer and allocate memory at runtime. But in this code, It is same as float data[3].

Comment: Then the better solution if you don't know the size of the array at runtime is to use a `std::vector`. Not only will it automatically delete itself, there is no chance of a memory leak whatsoever if additional code is added between the malloc() call and free() that can potentially throw an exception. `std::vector<float> data(3); ... env->SetFloatArrayRegion(result, 0, 3, &data[0]);` Also, IMO, writing JNI code is a huge reason to use RAII as much as possible.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Absolutly. I love std vector too. In this code, I want to write just simple code. If there is any chance to use vector or RAII or Smart pointer, I will choose that.