# How to get just an ordinary 1D array instead of a 2D array via JNI?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

So I have no experience with JNI, however I need to change a small part of the code I am given.

In my c++ code, I have this method defined (which java side code calls):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL sumTraces
  (JNIEnv* env, jclass caller, jobjectArray jPrestackArrays, jint count) {
```

The jPrestackArrays jobjectArray is a 2D float array [][] passed in by the java side. After the above code is:

```
float** prestack2D = (float**)malloc(nTracesIn * sizeof(float*));
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
   jfloatArray floatArrayJ = (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(jPrestackArrays, j);
   prestack2D[j] = (float*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(floatArrayJ, &isCopy);
}
```

And the code ends with:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    jfloatArray floatArrayJ = (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(jprestackTraces, j);
    env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(floatArrayJ, prestack2D[j], JNI_ABORT);
  }
```

And so that gives me a 2D array that I can use in the c++ code.

**However I need to change this code to instead just make it a normal 1D float array [] that java passes in** (such that float** prestack2D becomes float* prestack1D).

What exactly do I change in order to just get a normal float array? I tried GetObjectField and GetFloatArrayElements with no luck. I presume that this is a really answer easy question however like I said I have no experience with JNI and I am exhausted right now, and JNI's documentation is not as good as what I am used to.

Comment: Have you tried using 2D to 1D mapping (row * number_columns + column) and staying 1D full time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert float\* to jfloatArray using JNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011597/convert-float-to-jfloatarray-using-jni)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your Java method will be

```
static native void sumTraces(float[], int);
```

and its C++ side

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL sumTraces
    (JNIEnv* env, jclass caller, jfloatArray jPrestackArray, jint count);
```

Now, you can use

```
float* prestack1D = (float*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(jPrestackArray, &isCopy);
```

Don't forget to release:

```
env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(jPrestackArray, prestack1D, JNI_ABORT);
```

Note that you should always try release array locked with **GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()** as quickly as possible. The original code looks dangerous because if it locks many arrays, and does heavy processing, the Java VM may get starved.