# How to convert C++ Array<float,size> to jfloatArray in JNIWrapper?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I want to map my C++ **array** output to **jniFloatArray**.

Tried to follow this solution:

"[Convert float* to jfloatArray using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011597/convert-float-to-jfloatarray-using-jni)"

but I am unable to point float* to array object.

Let's say my output in C++ array output object is:

**output = {1.0f ,2.0f ,3.0f};**

What I really want is to convert or map this **output (array)** to **jfloatArray** in JniWrapper.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541568/c-and-jni-how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-jfloatarray

Comment: What do you mean by _"I am unable to point float* to array object"_ ?

Comment: @Michael let's say,
    array<float,320> output = {0};
then,
  float* ptr = output; // it gives error

Comment: @JoopEggen Actually, I want to map array<float,size> of c++ to jfloatArray in JNIWrapper.

Comment: If you want a pointer to the data in a `std:array`, use `output.data()`

Comment: @Michael Okay, let me try.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot. I was looking for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael solved the problem. So by using `output.data()` and setting float pointer to it as:

```
float *ptr = output.data();
```

solved the issue.